# France Train Stations 360° Images

Tags: online-resources, train-stations, sncf

What happened to [Gares 360](http://www.gares360.com/)? Is there a new website showing 360° images of SNCF train stations? This was extremely useful: passengers could find their way through complicated platforms and tunnels.

[image: SNCF Gare]

Answer (score 6):

It's gone ! [Official answer on the SNCF Q&A website](http://questions.sncf.com/questions/1519745-gares-360) :

> Indeed, there are no more 360° stations

It seems that what is suggested is to use https://www.gares-sncf.com/fr, where you can find (at least for some stations) a link to googlemap (example for Gare Montparnasse) : https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Gare+Montparnasse/@48.8410203,2.3198307,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb9036133d0fa1594!8m2!3d48.8410203!4d2.3203779

(Ironically, the 360 website was marketed as a step toward *digital innovation* a few years ago).